# Foolproof way to make sure a variable is storing/echoing all characters?

Tags: linux, bash, debugging

I've made a small function that I'm using when testing a script.

However I'm not sure it displays all characters, like spaces, quote, and stuff like that.

This is the function:

```
dbug () {

#  showing result during debug
zenity  --width 600 --height 100 --error --text="$@" --title="debug display"
}
```

And anywhere in the script where i want to check some variables I just add the line: `dbug $variable` and the pop-up window will show the result..

The question is, will the "$@" show all characters from the "call" command, or is something more fancy necessary?

Comment: `"$@"` can't be safely used in a string context at all -- it's an *array*, not a string.

Comment: Moreover, `dbug $variable` is buggy itself; you need to use it as `dbug "$variable"`, even once given an otherwise-correct implementation.

Comment: ...before we can specify what a "correct implementation" is, though, you need to decide *how you want nonprintable characters to be represented*.

Comment: Do you want to use `$'...'`-style strings, as done by the shell's `printf %q` builtin? Do you want to use `hexdump`-style content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One implementation that's capable of displaying nonprintable characters unambiguously would be:

```
dbug() {
  local text_q
  printf -v text_q '%q ' "$@"
  zenity --width=600 --height=100 --text="$text_q" --title="debug display"
}
```

This will transform tabs to `$'\t'`, newlines to `$'\n'`; will display spaces either within quotes or proceeded by backslashes; will double-up backslashes that are intended to be literal (when not displaying them in single quotes); and will otherwise ensure that the data is displayed is in a format where, if fed back to the shell as source code, *it will evaluate to its literal values*.

Comment: I think it broke zenity function, now it's not popping up at all..

Comment: *shrug*. zenity is a 3rd-party tool I'm not here to use or support. That said, something useful you *can* do is using `set -x` to enable debugging, so you can see how the shell is invoking zenity, and thus can reproduce the behavior without it. I would not be astonished if zenity itself were not capable of representing all possible strings; GUI frameworks often have special meanings for things.

Comment: (Also, make sure your shell really is bash; `printf %q` is not guaranteed to be provided by `/bin/sh`).

Comment: I'm using /bin/bash..  ok, let's skip zenity, and do it all shell, how do I print/echo the whole string, so all chars are being displayed (I just learned about -x)

Comment: To get output in the same format `set -x` gives you, `printf '%q\n' "$var"` is my go-to (when describing `var`).